# Duplicate sqs events in aws

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs

I have a service that calls an aws sqs queue which in turn executes a lambda function, and it rarely happens that this function is executed twice for the same queue message, and it shouldn't.

```
import aws from 'aws-sdk';
import { v4 as uuidv4 } from 'uuid';

import * as awsConfig from '../config/aws';

const accessKeyId = awsConfig.accessKeyId;
const secretAccessKey = awsConfig.secretAccessKey;
const region = awsConfig.generalRegion;

class SqsMessenger {
  sqs: aws.SQS;
  constructor() {
    this.sqs = new aws.SQS();
  }

  send(body: any, queueUrl: string, groupId?: string) {
    const params: aws.SQS.Types.SendMessageRequest = {
      MessageBody: JSON.stringify(body),
      MessageGroupId: groupId || uuidv4(),
      MessageDeduplicationId: uuidv4(),
      QueueUrl: queueUrl,
    };

    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      this.sqs.sendMessage(params, (error: aws.AWSError, data: aws.SQS.SendMessageResult) => {
        if (error) {
          return reject(error);
        }
        resolve(data);
      });
    });
  }
}

export const sqs = new SqsMessenger();
```

Lambda function logs

On the first call the MessageDeduplicationId field is displayed

[image]

And in the second call the MessageDeduplicationId field is no longer displayed, I emphasize that it does not happen all the time, but it should not be executed twice again.

[image]

Comment: how are you consuming it? what are the stats in the queue?

Comment: I understand that aws takes care of the consumption.

Comment: Is this a FIFO queue? Also, what is the `maxReceiveCount` on your queue? Could it be possible that your Lambda function failed to process the message and threw an error or something, so it is being retried?

Comment: Looking at your screenshots, those are two different messages with two completely different message IDs. Why do you think they are the same message?

Comment: The body has the same content, which is what we send from the service via sqs to the lambda function.